# Pyside GUI function overwrite issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside

I am learning to make GUI's in PySide.

- How do I re-size the buttons inside a QHBoxLayout()? I tried button_1.setFixedWidth() and button_1.setFixedHeight() these make the buttons non-scalable. button_1.move() also doesn't work.
- Also I have created a function angles() which have Qlabel and QLineEdit, when I run the program, the button function is over-writing the angles function to display only buttons at right corner of the GUI.
- And how to resize the length of the QLineEdit and for it to not extend the whole window?

  ```
  import sys
  from PySide.QtGui import *
  from PySide.QtCore import *

  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  #GUI Layout
      def __init__(self,parent = None):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

      widget = QWidget()
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
      self.setWindowTitle("Example")
      self.setGeometry(400, 100, 1500, 800)
      self.angles()
      self.makebuttons()

      def angles(self):
          central_widget = QWidget()
          self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

          Rotation = QLabel('Rotation:')
          Tilt = QLabel('Tilt:')

          RoatationEdit = QLineEdit()
          TiltEdit = QLineEdit()

          grid = QGridLayout()
          grid.setSpacing(2)

          grid.addWidget(Rotation,1,0)
          grid.addWidget(RoatationEdit, 1, 1)
          grid.addWidget(Tilt,2,0)
          grid.addWidget(TiltEdit, 2, 1)
          central_widget.setLayout(grid)

     def makebuttons(self):
         central_widget = QWidget()
         self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

         hbox = QHBoxLayout()
         button_1 = QPushButton("Button 1",self)
         button_1.move(0,30)
         hbox.addStretch(1)
         button_2 = QPushButton("Button 2",self)
         hbox.addStretch(1)
         hbox.addWidget(button_1)
         hbox.addWidget(button_2)

         vbox = QVBoxLayout()
         vbox.addStretch(1)
         vbox.addLayout(hbox)

         central_widget.setLayout(vbox)
       # central_widget.addLayout(vbox)


  if __name__ == '__main__':

      import sys
      app = QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = MainWindow()
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```

Comment: The makebuttons function creates another centralWidget by deleting all of the above, so you will not see what you did with angles.

Comment: If you want to resize use: button_1.setFixedSize({your scale}*button_1.size())

Comment: To change the width of QLineEdit use {your QlineEdit} .setFixedWidth({your width})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to resize use: `button_1.setFixedSize({your scale}*button_1.size())`
- The makebuttons function creates another centralWidget by deleting all of the above, so you will not see what you did with angles.
- To change the width of `QLineEdit` use `{your QlineEdit} .setFixedWidth({your width})`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did try your code for resizing the buttons and I get the error -  NotImplementedError: reverse operator not implemented.

Comment: @RaghavendraMG That you have placed exactly?

Comment: I placed the line below the declaration of the button_1. I added  a scale of 2.5.

Comment: @RaghavendraMG try with 2

Comment: @RaghavendraMG button_1.setFixedSize(2.5*button_1.size())

Comment: It did work with 2.5 ,Thanks. But if we use setFixedSize() it will make the button with a constant size and it wont resize accordingly to the window which is being resized to different resolutions.

Comment: @RaghavendraMG You asked yourself how to change the size, and that is the answer, if you want to keep the proportion you must use QLayouts

Comment: @RaghavendraMG 
When you post questions try to be as specific as possible.

Comment: I am trying my best ! Learning how to post , will do better. What I meant was I wanted to resize the button and still maintain its scalable property.

Answer (score 0):

I use *Qt Designer* for all of my *Pyside* GUI work, even if it's a fairly trivial program.  It's much more than just a drag-and-drop WYSISYG tool.  For things like push buttons in your example, you would be presented with a list of configurable properties including sizing parameters of the button as well as the ability to configure the layout.

So, my solution is to create your GUI in *QT Designer* then modify the layout there before using the `pyside-uic` tool to convert the code to `python`.  Then just import the resulting `python` module into your code.  From there you can still re-configure whatever you want later in your code if, for example, you need to change the appearance of your GUI during the course of your program.